# Create database if it doesn't exists with Dapper

Tags: c#, sql-server, database, dapper

Can I check if the database exists when creating the connection and if such a database does not exist, then run the script to create the database?
I use Dapper. 
This is how I create a connection:

```
private static IDbConnection GetConnection(IConfigHelper config)
        {
            var factory = DbProviderFactories.GetFactory("System.Data.SqlClient");

            var connection = factory.CreateConnection();
            connection.ConnectionString = config.ConnectionString;
            connection.Open();

            return connection;
        }
```

Different environments may be used in the future, so I need this check.

Answer (score 3):

Include this in your db-creation-script and simply allways run it upon initializing your connection.

```
IF NOT EXISTS(SELECT * FROM sys.databases WHERE name = 'yourDB')
  BEGIN
    CREATE DATABASE yourDB
  END
```

Comment: This answer helped me when I was trying to run a massive DB creation script that SQL Server Management Studio had created for me. I needed to run the CREATE DATABASE command as its own single statement before running the alters, creates (tables), etc.